# UIImageView disappears when aspect ratio constraint applied

Tags: ios, uiimageview, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

Xcode 9.3, MacBook Pro running OS 10.13.4

When I add an aspect ratio constraint to a `UIView` in IB, the view doesn't render in the simulator. Trying to find out where it went, I logged the relevant frame coordinates with the constraint absent, and then present. The coordinates appear identical, but see screenshots for difference.

With no constraints:

```
self.view.center = (207.0, 368.0)
self.thumbView.center = (93.0, 207.5)
self.viewFinder.center = (187.5, 163.5)
self.view.frame = (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 736.0)
self.thumbView.frame = (30.0, 174.0, 126.0, 67.0)
self.viewFinder.frame = (16.0, 75.0, 343.0, 177.0)
```

With only aspect ratio constraints:

```
self.view.center = (207.0, 368.0)
self.thumbView.center = (93.0, 207.5)
self.viewFinder.center = (187.5, 163.5)
self.view.frame = (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 736.0)
self.thumbView.frame = (30.0, 174.0, 126.0, 67.0)
self.viewFinder.frame = (16.0, 75.0, 343.0, 177.0)
```

Sure would appreciate some help if you've got any ideas!

Here's a shot of the scene in IB. The large `UIImageView` is `viewFinder`, the small one is `thumbView`:

[image]

Here's what it looks like with no constraints:

[image]

And here's what it looks like after I add the aspect ratio constraint:

[image]

**EDIT 1**

Per comment by @Anton below, I added Proximity restraints from the bottom and sides of the `viewFinder` to the `thumbView`. However, this produced no change--I still get coordinates that indicate the presence of `thumbView`, but it remains invisible.

Comment: Do you set those constraints by code or in interface builder? If first - then please show the code. In other case - check if there is any warnings/errors in interface builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: try adding also constraints for `x` and `y` position to the thumb view (for example align its' `leading` and `bottom` edges to `viewFinder`). You could get the same frames just because you check it before autolayout does its' job (in `viewDidLoad` for example). Also set some image to that image view or set constraint for one of the dimensions (without such constraint autolayout tries to use intrinsic size which depends on content for `UIImageView`). Also after that you have to check Interface builder for other errors, cause it most likely will require setting constraints to views, your `thumbView` depends on

If you do really have only one constraint for thumb view and its' aspect ratio constraint you probably get an error in interface builder which tells you that you have to set constraints for `x` and `y` coordinates of that view. Without such constraints you get an ambiguous layout which means that there are many variations of how to set the position of your view.

While there's no constraints at all, system translates `frame` and `autoresizing mask` of the view into constraints so that you got valid set of constraints to set view position and size, that's why view is visible. Since you add any constraints to view, you are supposed to add enough constraints to clearly define position and size of that view by those constraints.

Comment: Many thanks, Anton. However, it didn't change things. Please see my edit at bottom of question.

Comment: @rattletrap99 check out my edit - just aspect ratio also is not enough to set non-zero size. Hope that helps

Comment: I'm going to try a fairly major revision to my constraints and will report back after. Thanks!